# Python MapReduce How do i add a conditional statement

Tags: python, if-statement, hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to MapReduce and I am trying to find the average movie review for films in the MovieLens 100k dataset.  I have a working program that finds the average review for each movie, but what I want is to only do this for movies that have >100 reviews.  How can I add a conditional statement to do this?

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob

class PopularMovieAvgReview(MRJob):
    def mapper(self, key, line):
        (userID, movieID, rating, timestamp) = line.split('\t')
        yield movieID, float(rating)

    def reducer(self, movieID, rating):
        total = 0
        numElements = 0 
        for x in rating:
            total += x
            numElements += 1
        yield movieID, total / numElements

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PopularMovieAvgReview.run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to limit the output based on the number of ratings that were given

```
def reducer(self, movieID, rating):
    total = 0
    numElements = 0 
    for x in rating:
        total += x
        numElements += 1
    if numElements > 100:
        yield movieID, total / numElements
```

Alternatively, using PySpark, you can aggregate, then filter the ratings amount